# What is the cost of using exceptions in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa, exception, error-handling

I mean in the current implementation of clang or the gcc version.

C++ and Java guys always tell me that exceptions do not cost any performance unless they are thrown. Is the same true for Objective-C?

Comment: I'm rather sure that the C++ guys usually tell you that the costs of exceptions are *negligible* unless throwing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> C++ and Java guys always tell me that exceptions do not cost any performance unless they are thrown. Is the same true for Objective-C?

**Short Answer**

Only in 64-bit OS X and iOS.

They're not entirely free. To be more precise, the model is optimized to minimize costs during regular execution (moving consequences elsewhere).

**Detailed Answer**

On 32 bit OS X and iOS, exceptions have runtime costs even if they are not thrown. These architectures do not use Zero Cost Exceptions.

In 64 bit OS X, ObjC moved over to borrow C++'s "Zero Cost Exceptions". Zero Cost Exceptions have very very low execution overhead, *unless thrown*. Zero Cost Exceptions effectively move execution cost to binary size. This was one of the primary reasons they were not initially used in iOS. Enabling C++ exceptions and RTTI can increase the binary size by more than 50% -- of course, I would expect those numbers to be far lower in pure ObjC simply because there is less to execute when unwinding.

In arm64, the exception model was changed from Set Jump Long Jump to Itanium-derived Zero Cost Exceptions (judging by the assembly).

However, *Idiomatic ObjC programs are not written or prepared to recover from exceptions*, so you should reserve their use for situations which you do not intend to recover from (if you decide to use them at all). More details in the [Clang manual on ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#misc.exceptions), and in other sectons of the referenced page.

Comment: Also, you should point out the problems that exceptions cause for ARC: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html - "Making code exceptions-safe by default would impose severe runtime and code size penalties on code that typically does not actually care about exceptions safety. Therefore, ARC-generated code leaks by default on exceptions, which is just fine if the process is going to be immediately terminated anyway."

Comment: @BradLarson great reference -- thanks +1, and added. it may be worth noting that the only part that *is* truly specific to ARC at execution is: *"ARC does end the lifetimes of `__weak` objects when an exception terminates their scope unless exceptions are disabled in the compiler."*. the linked description certainly helps qualify examples of why exceptions cannot be recovered from (reliably, in a well-defined manner) in ObjC programs.

Comment: Thats fine for me. Hope they leave it that way :-) As an Eiffel programmer i hate exceptions and use them extremely limited.

Comment: @justin, thank you for your answer! Could you please tell, whether 64-bit iOS supports "zero-cost exceptions"?

Answer (score 6):

According to some 2007 release notes for the Objective-C runtime in Mac OS X v10.5, they have re-written the 64bit implementation of Objective-C exceptions to provide "zero-cost" try blocks and interoperability with C++.

Apparently, these "zero-cost" try blocks incur no time penalty when entering a try, unlike its 32-bit counterpart which must call setjmp() and other functions. Apparently throwing them is "much more expensive".

This is the only bit of information I can find in Apple's release notes so I would have to assume that this still applies in todays runtimes, and as such, 32bit exceptions = expensive, 64-bit exceptions = "zero-cost"

Comment: For completeness sake [64-bit Zero-Cost C++-Compatible Exceptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/RN-ObjectiveC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004309-CH1-DontLinkElementID_11)